# Best way to print the value of a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Which of the following is better coding style and why?

```
print("We have x = %i" %x)
print("We have x = "+str(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example was better. `print("We have x = %i" %x)` because you are working with a string object.  It takes less memory than working with 2 string objects and an int.

Since you are asking with a python3 tag, here is a newer format for python string formatting using str.format

```
dic = { 'x': '1'}
print("We have x = {x}".format(**dic))
```

or you can do this positionally:

```
print("The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2))
```

This works with 2.6+ and 3.3+

Comment: For most people I think the reason for using substitution is more about style than performance. According to this SO answer from 2008 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376461/string-concatenation-vs-string-substitution-in-python, concatenation is actually faster than substitution. However I don't know if this has changed with Python3.